# How do I create a conditional alias in .bashrc

Tags: bash

In my .bashrc I want to create an alias called `open`. This alias should behave like this.

Please note, this example is in sudo syntax:

```
alias open= if (target is a directory) then cd  
            else if (target is a file) then vi
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`xdg-open(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to these types of questions is nearly always "use a function":

```
open () {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        cd -- "$1"
    elif [ -f "$1" ]; then
        vi -- "$1"
    fi
}
```